# Find the solution of system of non linear equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The system of equations:

1. $x+2x^2+3xy+0y=6$
2. $2x+x^2+3xy+y=5$
3. $x-1x^2+0xy+y=7$

options are

1. has solutions in rational nos
2. has solutions in real nos
3. has no solution
4. has solutions in complex nos

Actually, I know to system of linear equations solving methods but I don't have any idea about to solve this kind  system of equations.
I guess the system of equations has solution is complex nos.  But I am not sure the answer.

Comment: Please check your system!

Comment: Why do you write $0y$? This is just zero. Or is it a typo?

Comment: yeah it is right ...no corrections in system

Comment: @DietrichBurde its just for our convenience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$i)x+2x^2+3xy=6\\ii)2x+x^2+3xy+y=5\\iii)x-x^2+y=7$$

We add $i)$ and $iii)$ to obtain $$x+2x^2+3xy+x-x^2+y=2x+x^2+3xy+y=13$$
But $ii)$ tells us that $2x+x^2+3xy+y=5$

Both cannot hold so the system has no solution.

Comment: no I didn't get

Comment: @GopiS Check my edit for a full answer.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Indeed, I had written it wrong though it works.. Thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

1. $x+2x^2+3xy+0y=6$
2. $2x+x^2+3xy+y=5$
3. $x-1x^2+0xy+y=7$

Multiply the second one with 2 and subtract eq 2 from eq 1.
Then $4x+2x^2+6xy+2y-x-2x^2-3xy=4 \implies 3x+3xy+2y=4$.
Similarly, $3x+2y=20 \implies 3xy=-14$.
So substitute this in the equation and you can proceed from here on.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I notice is that the third equation can be rewritten equivalently as $$x^2-x+7=y.$$ I also notice that the first and second equations both have $3xy,$ so subtracting the first from the second would give the equivalent system $$\begin{cases}x+2x^2+3xy=6\\x-x^2=5\\x^2-x+7=y.\end{cases}$$ Now I notice that the second and third are closely related, since $x^2-x=-(x-x^2),$ so adding the second to the third gives us the system $$\begin{cases}x+2x^2+3xy=6\\x-x^2=5\\7=y+5,\end{cases}$$ or $$\begin{cases}x+2x^2+3xy=6\\x-x^2=5\\2=y.\end{cases}$$ Substituting for $y$ in the first equation, we're left with two quadratic equations in $x,$ which you should be able to solve and draw the appropriate conclusion. Alternatively, we can add twice the second equation to the first (after substituting for $y$) to get $$\begin{cases}6x=16\\x-x^2=5\\2=y,\end{cases}$$ and so you only have to verify whether $x=\frac83$ is a solution to the second equation.

Answer (score 0):

Substituting $y=7+x^2-x$ from the third equation, the first two equations are
\begin{align*}
3x^3 - x^2 + 22x - 6 & = 0\\
3x^3 - x^2 + 22x + 2 & = 0
\end{align*}
Hence we obtain $8=0$, which gives a contradiction for all fields of characteristic different from $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: add equations -(1)+(2)-(3).